# UIView not firing methods in the UIScrollView delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I wonder if someone could please shed some light as to why any of the methods in UIScrollView delegate are not being fired.

To set the scene. I have a UIViewController which is pushed onto a stack. On this view I have 5 custom tabs that I have made. On a tap of each tap I have a function with loads of 5 views (one per tab) from UIViewController/xib combo.

```
ExercisePhotoView *exercisePhotoView = [[ExercisePhotoView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExercisePhotoView" bundle:nil];
exercisePhotoView.exercise = self.exercise;
[self.photoView addSubview:exercisePhotoView.view];
[exercisePhotoView release];
```

On one of these views that gets loaded I have a a scroll view with some images in (the above code block is the said view). The **self.exercise** is an NSManagedObject. The images are loaded fine into the scrollview controller and the paging works. What however does not work is any of the ScrollView's delegate methods such as

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)theScrollView
```

I have included a reference to the delegate in my header file like so.

```
@interface ExercisePhotoView : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView   *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIPageControl  *pageControl;

    Exercise                *exercise;
    NSMutableArray          *exerciseImageList; 
}
```

Is there something that I am missing or doing wrong. I cannot get any of the delegate methods to fire on the **ExercisePhotoView** class.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `self.scrollView.delegate` to the object that should act as a delegate to the scrollView.

Comment: Hi Philipp, thanks for your input, I have added the following "self.scrollView.delegate = self;" to my ExercisePhotoView. The app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS and after enabling NSZombies I now get the following error and have idea what is happening now. *** -[ExercisePhotoView respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5ce90a0

Comment: Just to clarify the crash only happens when trying to call on of the scrollView delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I have finally found the problem. It seems when I add the view to the main and at the line [exercisePhotoView release]; after I added the ExercisePhotoView was the route of all my evil.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you have stated that the ExercisePhotoView implements the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol, you have not informed it of any *instances* of a UIScrollView that it is the delegate for.

Therefore, in `viewDidLoad` of ExercisePhotoView (or other appropriate method), you need to declare that the ExercisePhotoView is the delegate for the specific scrollView instance:

```
scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView   *scrollView;` in your header and `@synthesize scrollView;` in your **.m**

Answer (score 0):

You must tell the scroll who it's delegate is, so that I knows who to send the delegate Notifications to.